# cant fetch image with mysql_fetch_object when fetching data from SQL

Tags: php, json

i have done this code in php and it fetches every detail correctly apart from the images it shows "product_photo":null while there is an image.
any ideas why is null?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($qry_result)){
     $result[] = $row;
}
$jsonstring = json_encode($result);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Comment: Nope, no idea at all. Errors? (You have to check for them.) You're trying to put an object into an array and then convert that array to JSON. That could be an issue.

Comment: there are no errors its just null

Comment: How are you checking for errors?

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and make sure you're getting the value. Also, what is  a valid value for that field?

Comment: my database is BLOB and i uploaded an image from the server and it was correctly done

Comment: Hmmmm, a BLOB in JSON?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). They are not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).